# How many soldiers you need to kill a supersonic swordsman?

Tags: magic, warfare

Myrsh is a halfbreed necromancer living in a xenophobic elven kingdom. He kidnapped the elven princess and trapped her inside a gemstone. He is very powerful and has supersonic speed. He wields a thin sword that reanimates his enemies after they die. **His sword can easily pierce steel**. The zombies are controlled by a psychic link. However, he can only effectively control 50 corpses.

The elves don't have supersonic speed but they have elemental mages that control fire and wind.

My anti-hero cannot flee from the elves using his speed because the kingdom is on an island.

**How many soldiers and mages you need to stop an enemy like Myrsh and save the heir of the elven kingdom, and how would they do it?**

*Notes:* The only way to kill the zombies is by incapacitation or cut their heads. Myrsh wears chain mail under his coat. The elves are decent warriors and mages but they are no match for the young necromancer at 1 vs 1 combat. The elven warriors wear plate armor, a broadsword, a heavy shield as well as a crossbow. The mages just wear clothes.

**The conflict takes place on a coast. Magic is limited by line of sight and physics**

**The elves need to be careful in the battle if they don't want to break the gemstone that contains the princess. If that happens, then she dies**

Comment: This is too story based.  The answer will depend on hundreds of details that are very specific to your world.  A trivial example would be that the quality of the soliders will matter.  Also, supersonic speed (aka The Flash) is known to be one of the worst physics-breakers out there.  There's all sorts of issues with that ability, and every single one of those issues will matter for trying to find a way to kill him.  Alternatively, the answer could be "just one."  Never underestimate the power of being in the right place at the right time.

Comment: Agreed. Agreed. And agreed. @CortAmmon you're hitting the nail on the head.

Comment: The elves don't need to be careful. If the endless supersonic shock waves (sonic booms) don't damage the gemstone, then it's hardy.

Comment: @user535733 Yes but you dont want to boil the princess alive.

Comment: Why would the elves bother fighting him? That's his strength. A smart enemy attacks weakness: Loneliness, susceptibility to poison, treachery, bribery, the One Ring, Twitter, whatever.

Comment: @user535733 WUT? Twitter?

Comment: @AlexDarkshine What does your speed matter if the ground you run on is destroyed. Create massive areas of destroyed ground. Get him onto one so his speed drops then snipe him.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the power of the mages, but if you've got enough archers, maybe eighty, even if he does have supersonic speed, they could shoot arrows all around him, along with the mages shooting spells, he'd die pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

To vague but it depends on the power of the mages. One or more keep blowing him up into the air till it hits lethal height, they then drop him till he splatters on the rocks below.

Otherwise they just set fire to the whole valley he's in. Burn it all down. Possibly keep him in there with gusts of wind.

Does your magic require line of sight? Otherwise just imagine his blood boiling and use the fire magic to do so.

Depending on how close he's to the ocean you could boil that. Kill him with the steam. With his speed he gotta breath and steam is a bad thing to breath. Actually they could use wind and fire to remove the oxygen around him so he suffocates.

Comment: Yes magic requires line of sight.

Comment: First two options stand, blow him up in the air till he drops dead. Or incinerate him.

Comment: But how can you incinerate him when he can dodge most attacks? Fire is not that fast.

Comment: Enough mages to carpet bomb the area. He can only move when he notices it.

Comment: @AlexDarkshine if you go this route, don't aim for the target. Carpet bomb the ground beneath him. He might be fast, but nothing escapes a furnace. The faster he moves, the worse his situation becomes. He'll only fan the flames and cook faster.

Comment: At supersonic, he might just blow the flames out :P